# Completing Capybara page should have content test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, haml

I am having a little problem understanding what process i need to follow in order to get this test to pass. I understand that the page should have content and I have data for that within the spec. I am not sure now what steps i need to follow in order to get my test to pass. So how do i pass the test notes to the page to complete this test? I am working in HAML.

**Test:**

```
  it "updates a diagnostic report" do 
diagnostic_info = FG.create(:diagnostic_info)
diagnostic_info.save!
visit edit_admin_diagnostic_path(diagnostic_info)
fill_in 'diagnostic_info_notes',    with: "test notes"
click_button "Save"
page.should have_content("Successfully updated")
page.should have_content("test notes")
end
```

**Edit view**

```
.field
        = label_tag :notes
        = f.text_field "notes"
        = submit_tag 'Save', method: :put, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }

    .field
        = link_to 'show', admin_diagnostics_path
```

**Show view**

```
  .field
    = label_tag :message
    = label_tag @diagnostic.data["message"] || :none
  .field
    = label_tag :appVersion
    = label_tag @diagnostic.data["appVersion"] || :none
  .field
    = label_tag :device
    = label_tag do
      %pre= JSON.pretty_generate(@diagnostic.data["device"])
  .field
    = label_tag :screenshot
    - if @diagnostic.data["screenshot"]
      = image_tag @diagnostic.data["screenshot"]
    - else
      = label_tag :none
  .field
    = label_tag :localStorage
    -if @diagnostic.data["localStorage"]
      = label_tag do
        %pre= JSON.pretty_generate(@diagnostic.data["localStorage"])
= link_to 'Delete', admin_diagnostic_path(@diagnostic), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'really?' }
= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_diagnostic_path
```

**Error**

```
  Failure/Error: page.should have_content("test notes")
   expected to find text "test notes"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you submit the form, do you get redirected to the edit page or the show page? In the show page I don't see that you show notes anywhere.

What I usually do in these cases is calling Capybara's

```
save_and_open_page
```

If you do so, you can see what content's actually on the page.